# Flutter-Xcode release build error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I want to run flutter project with release mode in xcode. I got this error

```
Failed to package /Users/yunusemrecelik/StudioProjects/my_project
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried to do flutter clean,pub get, pod deintegrate, pod install etc..

My flutter version is Flutter 2.10.4, Dart 2.16.2, xcode last version